# Store Analytics ClientID in Local Variable

Tags: vbscript, google-analytics

I'm trying to store the ClientID in a local variable but can't work out how to do this ?

To get the ClientId I have been using :

```
ga(function (tracker) {
    clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

But I cannot seem to get this function to do anything useful.

What I am looking to do is get this ClientID into a local variable using VBScript to then store this and append it to various items.

Usually this would be:

```
strLocalClientID= whateverFunction()
```

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to collect all tracker objects (unless you know the trackers name) and use the get method just like in the example

```
var trackers = ga.getAll();
for (var i=0; i < trackers.length; ++i) {
    var tracker = trackers[i];
    console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
}
```

If you have just one tracker (which will be usually the case) you can simplify this to

```
var trackers = ga.getAll();
var clientId = trackers[0].get('clientId');
```